# Ada pass limited private type to task

Tags: types, private, ada

I have a situation where I want to give a task a limited private type so it can call various functions on it (in particular it is a serial port from `GNAT.Serial_Communications`). I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work however.

I have tried passing it directly, which works right up until I have to use the type, at which point I can't copy it to a saved variable:

```
task body MyTask is
    MyT : LPType;
begin
    accept MyEntry (t : LPType) do
        MyT := t; -- not valid, LPType is limited private
    end MyEntry;
    -- Later I do something using MyT
end MyTask;
```

Since that didn't work I tried passing an access to the limited private type, unfortunately this still didn't work because of locality of accesses:

```
procedure MyProcedure is
    MyT : aliased LPType;
    Task : MyTask;
begin
    Initialize (MyT);

    Task.MyEntry (MyT'Access);
end MyProcedure;
```

I technically got it to compile by using an `Unrestricted_Access` but this feels like a hack and from my experience when you use a hack to bypass the compiler in Ada the compiler had a good reason to force you to do it and you've made a mistake.

So my question is: Is it possible to pass a limited private type to a task via an entry or is this simply a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ada the `limited` keyword indicates that the type doesn't have an assignment associated with it. This is pretty contrary to most mainstream languages but consider something like a [physical-]clock- or RNG-type: copying these make no sense, and so it makes sense to model things in this manner.

The `task` construct, however, isn't guaranteed to be in the same memory-space as the thread that calls into its entry. -- So we're at a bit of odds here: `limited` prohibits copying and the `entry` requires copying of some-sort.

There are several ways to get around this problem, but given the snippet of code that you've provided the solution would be to make the `task` a component of the `limited` type.

```
Package Example is
    Type LP is limited private;
    Function Create return LP;
    Function Create( Value : Integer ) return LP;
    Procedure Print( Object : LP );

Private

    Task Type Printer( Item : not null access LP ) is
        Entry Print;
    End Printer;

    Type LP is limited record
        Value     : Integer := 100;
        Task_Item : Printer(LP'Access);
    end record;

end Example;

Package Body Example is
    Function Create return LP is (others => <>);
    Function Create( Value : Integer ) return LP is
      (Value => Value, others => <>);
    Procedure Print( Object : LP ) is
    Begin
        Object.Task_Item.Print;
    end Print;

    Task Body Printer is
    Begin
        accept Print do
            Null;
        end Print;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( "Value:" & Integer'Image(Item.Value) );
    End Printer;
end Example;
```